# How to make cross-browser compatibility with IE10 and IE11?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, cross-browser, internet-explorer-11

I have this question: How can i make cross browser compatibility with IE 10 and IE11?

The reason is that from version 10 are no more accepted conditional stylesheets, that is how i have resolved the problem of cross browser compatibility so far.
I have always used them, taken from this quite good documentation:

http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/

And now i don't know what to do.
I have tried to make the general style fit to IE 11 and then make a special style for all the rest of the browsers (not IE), but yet i need conditional statement. And if i write this:

```
         <!--[if !IE]><!-->
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/not-ie.css" />
         <!--<![endif]-->
```

IE11 will link anyway to that css stylesheet, applying that style.
So i don't know how to divide the style for IE from the style for the rest.

Do you know what is the best way to proceed now?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Surely you're not suggesting you can use the same style sheet for all IE versions?

Comment: Sorry if not specified in the question! Basically for the versions of IE <= 9 there are not actually problems since i can still use conditional statement. So if there will be some differences i will make a stylesheet exclusive for a particular IE version.
The main point, that is what have asked, is how to make separate style for IE 11. Thanks anyway to point that out.

Comment: You can't, the IE developers were genius enough to decide that IE no longer needs conditional statements. You will need to use a javascript plugin like Modernizr

Comment: What exactly is it that has changed between IE10 and IE11 that makes you want a conditional stylesheet? For the most part I've found it's getting less and less necessary with each browser version. If you specify the actual problem, we may be able to help with it: there's a pretty good change there will be an easy solution that doesn't require you to detect the browser or version.

Comment: I have a problem with letter-spacing for a title. in Chrome i need exactly 0.18em and in IE 11 i need exactly 0.10em.
Then i have differences with the padding. There are about 40px of differences between IE and Chrome, and i need it for my main divs.
Maybe the next question for StackOverflow can be how exactly detect IE version > 9 with Modernizr, what do you think?

Comment: Padding ought to be pretty much identical between browsers. I'd be very surprised if you need to do anything browser-specific with padding these days. Your letter spacing thing sounds like a font issue, but I can't really tell without seeing it in action. Any chance of a jsfiddle demo to show us the issue?

Comment: do you have a link or can supply a JSFiddle that replicates the issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am with Spudley. What does your font-family value look like? Are you using a MAC to check Chrome, then a virtual machine to check IE? Check both Chrome and IE on the same machine. Also make sure you are not using a MAC only font as your lead font. Also are you using a CSS reset that evens out settings like letter spacing? Remember every browser has a base stylesheet and they are not all the same, so a reset is a way to even the rules out.

Comment: So the padding issue can be caused by something else, probably some other javascript. Anyway according to what you guys say, the answer to my original question "How to make cross-browser compatibility with IE10 and IE11?" basically is "don't worry, there is no need anymore to do that" I have understand correctly?

Comment: @johnnyfittizio: there certainly *shouldn't* be a need for it, no. Whether there is *actually* a need for it in this specific case is another question, but my feeling is that there's probably a solution here that doesn't require anything browser-specific. I haven't had a chance to really dig into your jsbin yet though, so I can't give you a definitive answer.

Comment: Thank you Spudley.
Don't worry with the Jsbin. Was not the question anyway. I managed to resolve the letter-spacing issue removing the font-size rule for the class(somehow there was a conflict). And the padding seems fine now. 
I am interested anyway how to check if the browser is IE > 9 using modernizr (to use as extreme solution in more complicate case where is not clear the source of the conflict). I will make a new question soon. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a PHP serve you could use PHPs "get_browser" function to determine the version and print a `<link>` tag according to the version retrieved. Or in Javascript, use something like "whichbrowser" (http://whichbrowser.net/) to detect it and then use document.write to print out an alternative `<link>` tag with the IE Stylesheet.